# Is there a way I can set only one of my groupboxes to scroll?

Tags: c#, scroll

```
Form1.AutoScroll = true;
```

I used this but it would only make the whole thing scroll (if the window size got smaller. I have multiple groupboxes. How do I make it so only one of my groupboxes will scroll instead? This is useful for making organizing lots of rows. I only need one of them to do that?

Answer (score 0):

GroupBox is not derived from ScrollableControl like UserControl or any other ContainerControl. So giving scrolling with AutoScroll will not be possible.

GroupBox is mainly used giving boundries to a set of control for example a set of radio buttons and "is" a control.

Though there is one difficult way to give scroll bar to groupbox ,and is by using VScrollBar and HScrollBar but you will have to do some child control movement handling on your own.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.hscrollbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

*** According to me groupbox is a confusing control and if your really wish to use a container use a UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

As @sunnytyra says GroupBox is not derived from ScrollableControl like UserControl or any other ContainerControl.
But if you want to do it you can add a panel inside a group box and than set

```
Panel1.AutoScroll = true;
```

It looks same as your GroupBox having a ScrollBar and it works same